# check combox contains particular string

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have a code like this for checking my string contains in combobox

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To cmbwarehouse.Items.Count - 1              
    If cmbwarehouse.Items.Contains(wh(1)) Then
         msgbox("Do somthing")
         Exit For
   Else
         MsgBox("Not a Valid warehouse and bin no", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
         Exit Sub
   End If
Next
```

but this is not working for me.what is the wrong in this code

Comment: I think you need: cmbwarehouse.Items(i).whatever

Comment: cannot give like this sir

Comment: cmbwarehouse.Items(i).ToString.Contains(wh(1)) <- like so.

Comment: cmbwarehouse.Items(i).ToString dot contains not getting

Comment: showing contains is not a member of string

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox` class has a [`FindString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx) method. You pass it a string, and it returns the zero-based index of the first item in your ComboBox that starts with that string. If it can't find a match, it returns -1. Much easier than writing your own `For` loop.

If you want to search for an *exact* match, rather than any item that starts with a string, you can call [`FindStringExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb.aspx).

Note also that both of these methods are overloaded with a second integer parameter. That allows you to start searching only at a particular index, if you wanted to ignore the items at the beginning of the ComboBox. Or if you wanted to find *additional* items beyond the first match (since these methods both stop and return the first match they find).

There is also an `Item` method that returns a collection of all the items in that ComboBox. But this is going to be more difficult to use to do what you want, since a combo box item doesn't even have to be a string. You can add anything that you want in there, as long as it inherits from `Object` (which is basically everything in the .NET world). So if you use `myComboBox.Items.Contains(...)`, it will search the object collection for the *exact* object that you specify. This is probably not what you want, since it is possible to have multiple `String` objects that contain the same text. Same problem with `myComboBox.Items.IndexOf(...)`.

Sample code:

```
' assuming wh(1) is a string...
Dim i As Integer = cmbwarehouse.FindStringExact(wh(1)
If (i <> -1) Then
    MsgBox("Found a matching item with index i.")
Else
    MsgBox("No matching item found.")
End If
```

Comment: showing FindStringExact is not a member of system.winodws.forms.combobox

Comment: Hmm, then there's something wrong with your setup. Because the documentation pretty clearly indicates that this exists. It is *possible* that it didn't exist back in version 1.0 of the .NET Framework. Surely you're not targeting that old of a version, are you?

Comment: That would have been helpful to mention in the question. Your options are to either write the loop yourself, or p/invoke to piggyback on the functionality included in the Win32 control. You'll need the SendMessage function to send the `CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT` message. Check http://pinvoke.net/ for help.

Comment: .Net 1.0... This is rare case nowadays - at least I have never encountered once till this.